# How to add prefix in order code in magento by payment methods

Tags: orders, sales-order, prefix

I need to add prefix in order number in magento.
Like If Order is Cash On Delivery Based then order no should to be like...
cod12332434343....
if order is prepaid..then it should be
pre12323233223 .... like this

if order is check/moneyorder then it should be....
cmo12121212121.....
For this i want to know that....how to add prefix in magento order number....before order create ....and saved in database.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order increment ID is generate by the class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric` (see table `eav_entity_type` column `increment_model`) which is invoked on order beforeSave via `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type::fetchNewIncrementId`.

Now the later has no knowledge of what it is actually rendering the increment ID for.  Where I normally would suggest using another `increment_model` ([as described by Atwix](http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-order-and-customer-numbers/)) this won't work.

The best solution in this case would probably be to use an observer. In this case you want to do that before the object is committed to database so we can use the `$this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before'` invoked by `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave`.

The order models eventPrefix is `sales_order` so that would make the event you want to observer `sales_order_save_before`.

Tying that all together we would get something like this in your [own custom module](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/)

`config.xml`

```
[...]
<global>
   <events>
        <sales_order_save_before>
            <observers>
                <[namespace]_[module]_sales_order_save_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>salesOrderSaveBefore</method>
                </[namespace]_[module]_sales_order_save_before>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_before>
        [...]
    </events>
    [...]
</global>
```

`[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Observer.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer 
{
    public function salesOrderSaveBefore($o)
    {
        $this->_generateOrderId($o);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _generateOrderId($o)
    {
        $_object = $o->getDataObject();

        if ($_object->isObjectNew !== true) // only set the increment of a new order
             return;

        $incrementId = $_object->getIncrementId(); // get original increment ID
        $payment = $order->getPayment();

        /**
         * Do some magic with payment methods 
         * to format the $incrementID
         */

        $_object->setIncrementId($incrementId); // set the new increment ID to be saved
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: this is untested code and might need some tender love and tweaking before you deploy it on a live environment.*

Comment: what is the use of this...$_object->isObjectNew ....not working with this condition...

Comment: Ah in that case just check if `$_object->getId()` is set

Comment: please review the answer...and remove Disclaimer

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, if you use some payment service provider like paypal etc. because you are getting directed to the service provider and then back to the shop. in this process you have the reserved order id, last incremend id etc. which have diverged.